# Hide Rows of GridView depending upon selection of CheckBox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I want to hide rows of a GridView if CheckBox in the first column of that row is checked.
If I select some checkboxes and click on deactivate Button then checked rows should be hided.
If I select some checkboxes and click on activate Button then checked rows should be displayed.

My code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace GalleryAnd_Album
{
    public partial class view_album : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRAVIN-LENOVO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gallery;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Album", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            DataBind();
        }


        protected void btnactive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                var chk = row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[1].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? Code seems to be OK.

Comment: I want to hide more than one row. Bt this code hides only one

Comment: How can I check if checkbox in each row is checked or not??
How can I hide that row accordingly??

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to use a variable to track each row, as it currently uses hard-coded index 1.
You can use the row.RowIndex property to track the particular row, so that the code looks like this:

```
GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Visible = false;
```